# Can not call procedure by JPA - could not determine data type of parameter

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timescaledb

When trying to call procedure with timestamp parameters by the code:

```
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                .withSchemaName("time_series")
                .withProcedureName("refresh_continuous_aggregate")
                .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("continuous_aggregate", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("window_start", Types.TIMESTAMP),
                        new SqlParameter("window_end", Types.TIMESTAMP));

        MapSqlParameterSource inParams = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("continuous_aggregate", "time_series.current_data_hourly", Types.VARCHAR)
                .addValue("window_start", "2020-11-12 01:02:03.123456789", Types.TIMESTAMP)
                .addValue("window_end", "2021-02-12 01:02:03.123456789", Types.TIMESTAMP);
        Map<String, Object> execute = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);
```

I'm getting error:

> ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler ->
> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call
> time_series.refresh_continuous_aggregate(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception
> is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data
> type of parameter $2

The similar error I'm getting when I try to use native query with dynamic parameters:

```
String queryStr = "CALL time_series.refresh_continuous_aggregate(?1, ?2, ?3)";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryStr)
        .setParameter(1, continuousAggregate)
        .setParameter(2, windowStart, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        .setParameter(3, windowEnd, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
Object singleResult = query.getSingleResult();
```

> ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -> ERROR: syntax error at or
> near "$2"

And by using StoredProcedureQuery:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("time_series.refresh_continuous_aggregate")
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("continuous_aggregate", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("window_start", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("window_end", Date.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .setParameter("continuous_aggregate", "time_series.current_data_hourly")
        .setParameter("window_start", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        .setParameter("window_end", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
query.execute();
```

> WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -> SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
> 42P18 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -> ERROR: could not
> determine data type of parameter $2

It looks like JDBC drivers issue.